In gtkmm-3.0, how do you use the Gtk::Widget::add_tick_callback function to call the on_tick function for a widget?
I'm trying to learn how to use gtk3. Using C, the gtk_widget_add_tick_callback function is very straightforward, and the gtk documentation is very easy to understand. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this in C++, the documentation for gtkmm-3.0 does not explain very well how to use this function. I want to use the main window's on_tick function to do something every tick.
guint Gtk::Widget::add_tick_callback(const SlotTick& slot)

is the function. SlotTick is:
using Gtk::Widget::SlotTick = sigc::slot<bool(const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::FrameClock>&)>

How do i get a sigc::slot<bool(const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::FrameClock>&)>?
I tried using get_frame_clock(), I tried using sigc::ptr_fun, and i tried using sigc::slot constructors. I was expecting to turn the get_frame_clock function, or the Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::FrameClock> into a sigc::slot. What actually resulted is compiler errors from the sigc++ library and from my C++ code.
#include <gtkmm.h>

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window {
public:
  MainWindow() {
    //add_tick_callback(?);
  }
protected:
  bool on_tick() {
    // do something
    return true;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = 
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.sample.minimumreproducible");

  MainWindow mainWindow;
  
  return app->run(mainWindow);
}


Provide a minimal reproducible sample please.

Please don't put the solution in your question. Instead, please scroll all the way down and post an answer to your question. Self-answers are encouraged. You'll be able to accept your own answer after 48 hours. Thank you.

I figured it out:
#include <gtkmm.h>

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window {
public:
  MainWindow() {
    add_tick_callback(sigc::mem_fun(this, &MainWindow::on_tick));
  }
protected:
  bool on_tick(const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::FrameClock>& frame_clock) {
    // do something
    return true;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = 
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.sample.minimumreproducible");

  MainWindow mainWindow;
  
  return app->run(mainWindow);
}


This answer was posted as an edit to the question (Solved) In gtkmm-3.0, how do you use the Gtk::Widget::add_tick_callback function to call the on_tick function for a widget? by the OP livphi under CC BY-SA 4.0.
